# Move Resource Manager tab in AS 3.6.1

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1

Since the update of AS to 3.6.1 the Resource Manager tab is placed above Project just as shown in the picture below.

[image: Default Position]

How can I make that the Resource Manager tab is below by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hold your mouse on resource manager tab and drag.** By this way you can set Resource Manager tab is below by default.

[image: move resource manager tab]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I already did this, I can move it manually, but once I open a new project it's back to the top.
Edit: I had to close all AS project, open one again, move the resource then close it for good. Now it stays down.